# Office automation: Messages and workflows, with individual dashboard

Tags: automation, office, dashboard

We are a small startup, and we want to setup an office automation system (internal dashboard, or say, paper-less office), with these features:

- Send/Receive letters and messages to/from employees
- Manage the workflow between employees, forward replies. etc.
- Individual dashboard for every person, to see incoming mails, to-dos, etc.
- Archive letters
- Generate reports
- ...

Any suggestions !?

Comment: Please explain exactly what is the difference between what you call "letter" and what you call "message", thanks!

Comment: Generate reports about what? Server load? Number of employees?

Answer (score 1):

Office Automation for small and medium-sized businesses usually use MS Office 365 suit for (email, document sharing, communicating, etc)  [MS Office 365 Information](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/explore-office-365-for-business)

For paperless solution I recommend E-copy Nuance product and its affordable for any size business. [E copy Nuance information](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-product/ecopy/index.htm)

Hopefully this was helpful

Comment: Thanks @SolutionSurfers for your answer. Is there any complete and comprehensive software, so that we don't have to install and run two softwares?

Comment: Do the recommended software suits meet the requirements? Answers should list that. They should also list what makes the recommended software recommendable, and if there's a price-tag attached (plus how much that is then). Could you please [edit] your post and fill the gaps (see our [answer quality guide](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) if you need some help on this)? AFAIK Office365 will require a subscription (with a subscription fee), and I've no idea if Nuance comes "for free". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Liferay can do this. Most of it is free and open source, but the workflow part is only in the Enterprise edition.

- Send/Receive letters and messages to/from employees: Yes with the [email portlet](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/integrating-your-email-with-liferay-mail), see screenshot below
- Manage the workflow between employees: Yes Liferay has [workflows](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/using-workflow) in the Enterprise edition, see screenshot below
- Individual dashboard for every person, to see incoming mails, to-dos, etc: Yes
- Archive letters: Yes, you can create a folder called "Archive" and use it as such.
- Generate reports: Liferay generates reports about tons of different things

[image: Liferay email]

[image: Liferay workflow]